# JSLint "This function needs a "use strict" pragma."

Tags: javascript, jslint, strict

Anyone know the cause of the "This function needs a "use strict" pragma." errors i get when JSLinting this code? I could fix this by adding "use strict"; to all of my functions, but i'd rather know how to fix it alltogether. Cheers!

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true,  white: true, long: true, for: true*/
/*eslint-env browser*/
/*eslint 'no-console':0*/

var metronomebutton = document.querySelector("#playMetronome");
var stopmetronomebutton = document.querySelector("#stopMetronome");
var playing;
var audiobutton1 = document.querySelector("#c1Button");
var audiobutton2 = document.querySelector("#d1Button");
var audiobutton3 = document.querySelector("#e1Button");
var audiobutton4 = document.querySelector("#f1Button");
var audiobutton5 = document.querySelector("#g1Button");
var audiobutton6 = document.querySelector("#a1Button");
var audiobutton7 = document.querySelector("#b1Button");
var c1 = new Audio("Piano/c1.mp3");
var d1 = new Audio("Piano/d1.mp3");
var e1 = new Audio("Piano/e1.mp3");
var f1 = new Audio("Piano/f1.mp3");
var g1 = new Audio("Piano/g1.mp3");
var a1 = new Audio("Piano/a1.mp3");
var b1 = new Audio("Piano/b1.mp3");
var metronome = new Audio("Piano/tick.wav");
var artiesten = ["Mozart", "Beethoven", "Chopin"];
var i;



function dagartiest(artiesten)  {               //kiest een random artiest uit de array

    return artiesten[Math.floor(Math.random()* artiesten.length)];

}

for (i = 0; i < artiesten.length; i+=1) {       //Laat alle artiesten uit de array in de console zien

    console.log(artiesten[i]);
}

function playAudio() {                          //speel de noot c1

    c1.play();
    c1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio1() {                         //speel de noot d1

    d1.play();
    d1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio2() {                         //speel de noot e1

    e1.play();
    e1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio3() {                         //speel de noot f1

    f1.play();
    f1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio4() {                         //speel de noot g1

    g1.play();
    g1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio5() {                         //speel de noot a1

    a1.play();
    a1.currentTime =0;
}

function playAudio6() {                         //speel de noot b1

    b1.play();
    b1.currentTime =0;
}


function playMetronome(){
    playing = setTimeout(playMetronome, 500);   //speel elke halve seconde metronome af
    metronome.play();
}


function stopMetronome(){                       //stop timeout van de metronome
        clearTimeout(playing);
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {              //speel de noot c1 als de a toets is ingedrukt
    if (e.which === 65){
        c1.play();
        c1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("c1Button").classList.add("c1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 83){               //speel de noot d1 als de s toets is ingedrukt
        d1.play();
        d1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("d1Button").classList.add("d1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 68){               //speel de noot e1 als de d toets is ingedrukt
        e1.play();
        e1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("e1Button").classList.add("e1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 70){               //speel de noot f1 als de f toets is ingedrukt
        f1.play();
        f1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("f1Button").classList.add("f1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 71){               //speel de noot g1 als de g toets is ingedrukt
        g1.play();
        g1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("g1Button").classList.add("g1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 72){               //speel de noot a1 als de h toets is ingedrukt
        a1.play();
        a1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("a1Button").classList.add("a1active");

    }   else if (e.which === 74){               //speel de noot b1 als de j toets is ingedrukt
        b1.play();
        b1.currentTime =0;
        document.getElementById("b1Button").classList.add("b1active");

    }
};


document.onkeyup = function(e){                 //verander css als een toets omhoog gaat
        document.getElementById("c1Button").classList.remove("c1active");
        document.getElementById("d1Button").classList.remove("d1active");
        document.getElementById("e1Button").classList.remove("e1active");   
        document.getElementById("f1Button").classList.remove("f1active");
        document.getElementById("g1Button").classList.remove("g1active");
        document.getElementById("a1Button").classList.remove("a1active");
        document.getElementById("b1Button").classList.remove("b1active");
};


document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Artiest van de dag: " + dagartiest(artiesten);
audiobutton1.addEventListener("click", playAudio, false);
audiobutton2.addEventListener("click", playAudio1, false);
audiobutton3.addEventListener("click", playAudio2, false);
audiobutton4.addEventListener("click", playAudio3, false);
audiobutton5.addEventListener("click", playAudio4, false);
audiobutton6.addEventListener("click", playAudio5, false);
audiobutton7.addEventListener("click", playAudio6, false);
metronomebutton.addEventListener("click", playMetronome);
stopmetronomebutton.addEventListener("click", stopMetronome);
document.addEventListener("load", dagartiest);
```

Here's the error

```
Undeclared 'Audio'.
var c1 = new Audio("Piano/c1.mp3");
15.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var d1 = new Audio("Piano/d1.mp3");
16.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var e1 = new Audio("Piano/e1.mp3");
17.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var f1 = new Audio("Piano/f1.mp3");
18.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var g1 = new Audio("Piano/g1.mp3");
19.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var a1 = new Audio("Piano/a1.mp3");
20.13Undeclared 'Audio'.
var b1 = new Audio("Piano/b1.mp3");
21.20Undeclared 'Audio'.
var metronome = new Audio("Piano/tick.wav");
27.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function dagartiest(artiesten)  {               //kiest een random artiest uit de array
33.0Expected 'for' to be in a function.
for (i = 0; i < artiesten.length; i+=1) {       //Laat alle artiesten uit de array in de console zien
38.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio() {                          //speel de noot c1
44.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio1() {                         //speel de noot d1
50.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio2() {                         //speel de noot e1
56.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio3() {                         //speel de noot f1
62.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio4() {                         //speel de noot g1
68.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio5() {                         //speel de noot a1
74.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playAudio6() {                         //speel de noot b1
81.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function playMetronome(){
87.0This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
function stopMetronome(){                       //stop timeout van de metronome
91.21This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
document.onkeydown = function(e) {              //speel de noot c1 als de a toets is ingedrukt
131.19This function needs a "use strict" pragma.
document.onkeyup = function(e){                 //verander css als een toets omhoog gaat
```

JSHint doesn't give me any errors.

Also, if anyone could help me figure out why it's also complaining about Audio being undeclared, i would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint enforces rules that its author, Douglas Crockford, thinks are appropriate. One of those is to require that you write code in strict mode. *(I happen to agree that this is best practice.)*

Unfortunately, JSLint also complains if you put `"use strict";` at the top of the file if you tell it you're targeting a browser (which is bizarre, as that's it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do).

So your choices are:

1. Put `"use strict";` at the top of every function.
2. Don't tell it you're targeting a browser, supply all the globals yourself, and add `"use strict";` at the top of the file:

   ```
   "use strict";
   /*jslint browser: false, devel: true,  white: true, long: true, for: true*/
   /*global
   clearInterval, clearTimeout, document, event, FileReader, FormData, history, localStorage, location, name, navigator, screen, sessionStorage, setInterval, setTimeout, Storage, URL, window, XMLHttpRequest
   */
   /*eslint-env browser*/
   /*eslint 'no-console':0*/

   var metronomebutton = document.querySelector("#playMetronome");
   var stopmetronomebutton = document.querySelector("#stopMetronome");
   // ...
   ```
3. Use something else, like [ESLint](https://eslint.org). (And I notice you have a couple of ESLint-oriented comments in that code.) It offers better documentation and more control over the rules. For instance, its equivalent of this `strict` rule is documented [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've tried adding "use strict"; to the top of the page, this however, presents me with Unexpected 'use strict'.
"use strict"; as the first error, and completely negates all of the other jslint exceptions ive written underneath.

Comment: @RickChardet - Yeah, I just updated the answer. I went to check something on the JSLint page and found that its `browser` option disallows `"use strict";` at the top of the file. (Characteristically with no explanation of why Crockford thinks disallowing that is a good thing.)

Comment: Cheers, i appreciate the help! Think i'll manage from here :)